# Is there a Google Play Kindle equivalent?

Tags: e-reader

Is there a device that's Google Play but like a Kindle? I'm not looking to get a full up computer/tablet/etc - I'm just looking for an ebook reader but I specifically need Google Play. Desired specifications:

- I don't want to have to navigate around Windows to reach my books or have to maintain Windows

  - This is why I'm really looking for a dedicated device - I only want to read on it
- Comparable text resolution - this is one of the principal things I do appreciate about Kindle
- Google Play's standard translate / dictionary functionality

I speak Mandarin and for reasons unclear to me, despite more than a decade of people asking, Kindle still does not really support Traditional Chinese (unicode is hard I guess). It will render on your phone / Kindle device, but dictionaries don't work and you're limited to Bing for translations and to say Bing does poorly is generous. The formatting for vertical text is also not great a lot of the time.

Google Play however, works like a champ.